# Can lighthouse-ci output the line of code that has error?

Tags: lighthouse, lighthouse-ci

Currently using lighthouse-ci for CI pipeline. Whenever I run lighthouse-ci, the terminal output shows the failings of the website, but does not show which exact line of code is erroneous. The chrome extension however, does show the line of code that is erroneous. Is it possible to configure lighthouse-ci such that they show in the terminal output?